# Is it supported to use shared mailboxes in SharePoint 2013 Workflows

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, exchange

We try to send an email to a shared mailbox (Exchange 2007) from a workflow in SharePoint 2013. No errors are shown in the workflow but the message does not arrive in the mailbox. If we do the same with an user mailbox it works.

Both Exchange and SharePoint are on-premises.

Is it supported to use shared mailboxes in SharePoint 2013 Workflows?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, afraid SP Workflow 2013 doesn't support it as far as i know, but you can trigger SP Workflow 2010 from SP WF2013 to send the email to Shared Mail.

Comment: Always found this to be the quickest way to implement emails being sent to external mailboxes/shared mailboxes. Use your 2013 workflow and trigger a 2010 workflow from there. In your 2010 workflow you can perform the email function as per usual.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the sharepoint 2010 workflow engine. I have been seeing errors in relation to this behaviour and it was identified that the error is that it cannot find the email address. Still investigating with MS Support. However we found that using the 2010 workflow engine it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when adding a shared mailbox as a recipient in a Designer workflow. Creating a variable to hold the email address worked for me.  The steps to complete are:

1)  In the workflow, create a local variable.  Name = [mailbox name] / Type = [string]

2)  In the workflow step, add the “Set Workflow Variable” action before the “Send an email” action.

3)  In the “Value” section, enter the shared mailbox email address.

4)  In the “Send an email” action, select the address book, in the “Select from existing Users and Groups” section select “Workflow Lookup for a User…,” and then click Add.

5)  In the “Data source” drop down, select “Workflow Variables and Parameters.”

6)  In the “Field from Source” drop down, select your variable and leave the “Return field as” drop down as “As String.”

Answer (score 0):

This is one of Microsoft's annoying "design features".

The problem is that cannot enumerate the mailbox as a SharePoint user. To get around this, you can add the mailbox to the members group of a site and magically the workflow should stop giving errors that it cant send to that address.

I have verified this using SP Online as I had exactly the same problem today, hopefully it should also work with your configuration if everything is on the same AD. My workflow is now working as expected and I've not had to resort to using a 2010 workflow as I have done in the past to send emails to external mail addresses (which itself mysteriously stopped working some months ago).

Comment: how do you do this? I have the same problem and when I try to add the shared mailbox address to site members it says no results found

Answer (score 0):

This may be because on your AD connection for User Profile Service your filtering out disabled accounts. Shared Mailbox accounts are disabled in AD therefore won't get imported into UPS and won't be available to be added to the site via People Picker. We're also facing the same issue. I also don't want to include disabled accounts in UPS AD connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem this week.  We use SharePoint 2013 on prem and Exchange on prem. When I created the shared mailbox Exchange automatically created a user with the same name.  That user was disabled by default (which makes sense, so one should log in with that user).  However, our SharePoint does not import disabled users.  In fact we also require that AD must have a city populated for users too.

I enabled the account and added a city and then I did a full import on the user profiles.  Once that was done then I could add the user to the workflow. I tested the workflow with the shared mailbox user enabled for a while and then after a day I disabled the user again.  The workflow has continued to run fine with the user disabled. If that changes then I will post an update, but I think the key thing is that once that user for the shared mailbox is imported into the user profiles then the workflow will be able to look up the user information that it needs.

Also, I did this in a SharePoint 2013 workflow, not a 2010 one.